# ggplot with multiple variables, how to use it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my datas :

```
> dput(head(DTA_ecart))
structure(list(VARIETE = structure(c(21L, 10L, 19L, 8L, 25L, 
9L), .Label = c("JAIDOR", "SOVERDO CS", "LG ANDROID", "RGT GOLDENO", 
"LG ABSALON", "SYSTEM", "SOPHIE CS", "FRUCTIDOR", "AUCKLAND", 
"CELLULE", "HYNVICTUS", "KWS DAKOTANA", "RGT PULKO", "PASTORAL", 
"RGT CESARIO", "ALBATOR", "TRIOMPH", "UNIK", "RUBISKO", "SANREMO", 
"BERGAMO", "APOSTEL", "NEMO", "CREEK", "ADVISOR", "LUMINON", 
"COMPLICE", "CONCRET", "MUTIC", "FILON", "RGT VOLUPTO", "RGT LIBRAVO", 
"MAORI", "GEDSER", "AMBOISE", "LEANDRE", "KWS EXTASE", "JOHNSON", 
"RGT SACRAMENTO", "CHEVIGNON", "TENOR", "HYKING"), class = "factor"), 
    MOY_AJUST_GENE = c(99.7895968050932, 98.3815438187667, 99.5870260220881, 
    97.6906515272718, 100.211944045668, 98.2284907307116), `2018` = c(98.1347176686395, 
    96.1164669271045, 100.231262619975, 97.9346324658149, 101.492669333435, 
    98.3348028714641), `2017` = c(99.6983386400334, 98.7327100524886, 
    99.898423842858, 97.6800878984984, 100.411685884886, 99.4721553672752
    ), `2016` = c(108.358004643877, 96.8226577332073, 99.5281576496616, 
    95.8309310757289, 96.0223169219089, 95.5438523064588), `2015` = c(97.6405945592034, 
    98.7019160698383, 99.3456684615348, 99.6588453007385, 102.921104042444, 
    99.5631523776484), `2014` = c(100.628418176586, 99.3061159666147, 
    97.0268845257432, 97.3487607215915, NA, NA), `2013` = c(97.5528091773162, 
    98.7794184641974, 100.56278657633, NA, NA, NA), grp = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
    "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", 
    "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is my code for ggplot2 :

```
ggplot(DTA_ecart, aes(y = DTA_ecart[, 1])) +

  geom_point(aes(x = DTA_ecart[, 2]), color = "black", size = 2, na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = DTA_ecart[, 3]), color = "black", size = 1, group = DTA_ecart[, 9], na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = DTA_ecart[, 4]), color = "black", size = 1, group = DTA_ecart[, 9], na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = DTA_ecart[, 5]), color = "black", size = 1, group = DTA_ecart[, 9], na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = DTA_ecart[, 6]), color = "black", size = 1, group = DTA_ecart[, 9], na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = DTA_ecart[, 7]), color = "black", size = 1, group = DTA_ecart[, 9], na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = DTA_ecart[, 8]), color = "black", size = 1, group = DTA_ecart[, 9], na.rm = TRUE) +

  # geom_line(data = DTA_ecart, aes(x = DTA_ecart[, 9], y = DTA_ecart[, 1], color = "black")) +

  geom_vline(xintercept = 100) +
  xlim(90, 110) +
  ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(main.title), atop(italic(.(sub.title), ""))))) +
  xlab(x.title) +
  ylab("")
```

How to simplify this code, I'm not sure if it's the right way to import multiple x variable but it work and it's handly.

However, I would like to connect each dots with lines (`geom_line` I guess). I made groups, in the last column of my data frame `DTA_ecart[, 9]` to connect them. What is the code to draw this line ?

Also, I would like to add labels on each points with the name of the column used : 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014 or 2013.

Thank you,

Comment: I think you need to `melt` your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. I used `geom_text_repel` because some of the years would otherwise overlap with each other. But it does make the plot a bit more cluttered. You can also just use `geom_text` and try to adjust the labels accordingly.

```
library(ggrepel)
DTA_ecart %>%
  gather(year, value, -VARIETE, -MOY_AJUST_GENE, -grp) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = VARIETE)) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 100) +
    geom_line(aes(group = grp)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_point(aes(x= MOY_AJUST_GENE), size = 2, color = "red", alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = year)) +
    xlim(90, 110) +
    ylab("")
```

[image]

Comment: It's so perfect, thank you ! I couldn't find it alone... Also, is there a way to write the year with only the two last numbers (example : 2018 became 18) ? I tried  `geom_text_repel(aes(label = (year - 2000))` but it doesn't works.

Comment: In your data the year is stored as a character and not a numerical or date column so you can't do math with it. This is the fastest fix: `geom_text_repel(aes(label = as.numeric(year) - 2000))`. 
If this answer solved your problem you can consider accepting it so other people also know this answer solves the question.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It would suggest to get your data tidy in the sense of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html. Then plotting with ggplot is quite simple - otherwise you fight against ggplot thereby creating difficult to maintain code.
Something like

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble) 
x <- # your data frame as above
x <- as_tibble(x)
y <- x %>% gather("YEAR", "value", -VARIETE, -MOY_AJUST_GENE, -grp)
```

Now you get a tidy data frame

```
# A tibble: 36 x 5
   VARIETE   MOY_AJUST_GENE grp   YEAR  value
                    
 1 BERGAMO             99.8 1     2018   98.1
 2 CELLULE             98.4 2     2018   96.1
```

From this point you could simply call something like this

```
ggplot(y %>% drop_na(), aes(x=YEAR, y=value, color=VARIETE)) + geom_point()
```

for plotting.

Comment: Ah I didn't see your reply in time. I suggested pretty much the same thing, but also added a plot with the desired line and an option for the text annotation.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot !

Comment: Some new things on my work. I have ncols after "grp" on my data.frame. How should I ignore them ? I tried : `x %>% gather("YEAR", "value", -VARIETE, -MOY_AJUST_GENE, -grp:ncol(data))` but it doesn't work..

Comment: What about
`igrp <- match("grp",names(x)):ncol(x)` and then

`x %>% gather("YEAR", "value", -VARIETE, -MOY_AJUST_GENE, -igrp)`